# Pre-render link attribute not causing resources to load

Tags: javascript, html, prerender, prefetch

So, my website consists of html and javascript, nothing special.

At some point in time the user will be redirected to a website like youtube via javascript:

```
window.location = "https://www.youtube.com"
```

In order to load it as fast as possible I added `<link rel="prerender" href="https://www.youtube.com">` to the header in my html-file.

However, the site is not prerendered and aside from my website's content, there is no network activity shown in the dev console.

I tried prefetching instead of prerendering, which works but is too slow in this case.

I'm using Opera, latest version.

Comment: I can reproduce this. `prefetch` works, but not `prerender`. In fact `prerender` doesn't seem to work for _any_ domain I try. Maybe it's just disabled? (Using latest Chrome).

Comment: While Wikipedia says "prerender" is not available, other websites state that it is. Network prediciton is activated in settings. Other than these hints, I couldn't find any information on whether prerender is available.

Comment: I can't get it to work with any settings. I tried enabling "Use a prediction service to load pages more quickly" in settings and forcing the `No-State Prefetch` flag.

Comment: I tried "preconnect" and some other options too, the only thing that works seems to be "prefetch"